# How can I get only one US value?

Tags: javascript, php

**I make a request and get an answer**

Request:

```
<?php foreach($tv_id_re->content_ratings->results as $re){ ?>
       <p><h2 id="rate"><?php echo $re->rating ?></h2></p>
```

Answer:

```
content_ratings":{
   "results":[
            {"iso_3166_1":"DE","rating":"18"}, 
            {"iso_3166_1":"US","rating":"TV-MA"},
            {"iso_3166_1":"NL","rating":"16"}
             ]
     }
```

How do I get a US response only?

Comment: Is this a kind of javascript question or php question ??

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with [reactjs]...
Anyway... try 
`const results = content_ratings.results.filter(item => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');`

Comment: Do you want the api response to only return only result or do you want to parse only one result from the response?

Comment: Yes only US result

Comment: Answer an “or” question with “yes”, that is great.

Comment: I need exactly the US: Name rate. The rest is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the results on the frontend, you can use Array's `filter` method.

```
const us_records_only = content_ratings.results.filter(item => item.iso_3166_1 === 'US');

console.log(us_records_only);
// [{ iso_3166_1: "US", rating: "TV-MA" }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to filter out the results that don't match your criteria. One way is to apply a filter on the array using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter).

```
$result = array_filter($tv_id_re->content_ratings->results, function ($val) {
    return $val->iso_3166_1 === 'US';
});

var_dump($result);
/**
 * array(1) {
 *   [1]=>
 *   array(2) {
 *     ["iso_3166_1"]=>
 *     string(2) "US"
 *     ["rating"]=>
 *     string(5) "TV-MA"
 *   }
 * }
 */
```

Comment: `<div class="allnis">
<?php foreach($tv_id_re->content_ratings->results as $re){ ?>
     <p><h2 id="rate"><?php echo $re->rating; ?></h2></p>
<?php }   ?>
</div>`
**How to apply a filter US to it ?**

Comment: See the answer above ^